# WebRTC only works locally even after deploying to Heroku

Tags: heroku, webrtc, easyrtc

`WebRTC` only works locally even after deploying to `Heroku`.
I am using [`EasyRTC`](https://easyrtc.com/) and their [demo files from GitHub](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc).

All works great in `localhost`. I also deployed the files using `Heroku`, which also worked great locally (in `LAN`, same Wifi).
But when I tried it in `WAN` it did not work and started to give errors.

Please help on any ways to fix this or a suggestion for another deployment method or `webrtc` library.

Comment: What errors are you getting? We cannot help without more information. Contrary to popular belief, we're not magicians (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a TURN server such as coturn. See https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/ in the description "Example #1 – My WebRTC app works locally but not on a different network!" for a description how to diagnose these problems. See also https://bloggeek.me/google-free-turn-server/ for why you need to run your own or pay for it.